# Unable to insert in MySQL database using prepared statement

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

The code i used for data insertion.
The process working fine till the execute statement.Not sure why i am facing this issue.

```java
package com.emandi.dao;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Statement;
import com.emandi.dbconnection.DBConnection;
import com.emandi.domain.Item;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ItemDAO {

    public void createItem(Item item) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

       Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();

       String query = "insert into item(item_id, item_name, total_quantity, available_quantity,date,user_id,item_type_id)"

        + " values (?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?)";

      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

      Long a12= item.getItemId();

      preparedStmt.setLong(1,a12);
      preparedStmt.setString(2,item.getItemName());
      preparedStmt.setDouble (3,item.getTotalQuantity());
      preparedStmt.setDouble (4,item.getAvailableQuantity());

      //java.sql.Date d= new java.sql.Date(format.parse(source).getTime());
      java.util.Date utilStartDate = item.getDate();

      java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate.getTime());

      preparedStmt.setDate(5,sqlStartDate);

      Long as = item.getUser().getUserId();

      preparedStmt.setLong(6,as);

      Long as1 = item.getItemType().getItemTypeId();

      preparedStmt.setLong(7,as1);  

      System.out.println("Before");

      preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

      System.out.println("After");

    }

}
```

The Class item is as follows

```java
public class Item {

    private Long itemId;
    private User user;
    private ItemType itemType;
    private String itemName;
    private Double totalQuantity;
    private Double availableQuantity;
    private Date date;
}
```

I have also now attached the output screenhot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXk79.png)

Now i also updated the insert query using correct spelling for Total_quantity.

Still facing the issue

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I am guessing the error is something to the effect of "column 'toatal_quantity' does not exist."

Comment: there is no error. message given. The job exited at that step preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

Comment: i have attached the output screeshot

Comment: You may want to tag with java.